PrimeNG (16.9.15-lts) Autocomplete Bug: Selected Object Becomes String Instead of Object
I am working on an Angular project that uses p-autoComplete to allow users to select a movie from a list. The autocomplete works well, but I’ve run into a strange issue.
When a user selects a movie by typing the full title and clicking out of the field, the selectedMovie object is set correctly, and everything works as expected. However, if the user then focuses on the field again, deletes any character of the field, and then re-types the same character, when the user clicks out of the field, the selectedMovie variable is set to a string (the movie title) instead of the full Movie object.
I set [forceSelection]="true" in the autocomplete component to ensure that only valid movie objects can be selected.
I also checked the onBlur() method and logged the value of selectedMovie, expecting it to always contain the full Movie object, even after modifying the input. I have managed to replicate the bug into the following stackblitz,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/wkppg3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fautocomplete-basic-demo.ts
Update:
Sketchy workaround:
In the onBlur() method, I added a check to determine if selectedMovie is a string instead of the expected movie object. If it is a string I search for the corresponding movie object in the movies array using the movie title, and then reassign selectedMovie to that movie object.
onBlur(event: Event): void {

  if (typeof this.selectedMovie === 'string') {
    // Find the string into the array of movies and reasign it to the selectedMovie
    console.log('selectedMovie was a string.. ', this.selectedMovie);
    const movieToTransform: string = this.selectedMovie;
    this.selectedMovie = this.movies.find(movie => movie.title === movieToTransform);
    console.log('updated selectedMovie: ', this.selectedMovie)
  }
}


The component is correct. The problem is that the "blur" is executed also when you "click" the option. (if you write in html {{selectedMovie|json}} you always see an object

Thank you for your response, but unfortunately, that doesn't solve the issue I'm facing. The blur event is not the main problem here. The issue arises after the user modifies the input (e.g., deletes a character and re-adds it), at which point selectedMovie is no longer an object but a string containing only the title.

Really, no, but you need take account that while you're writing yes is a string, so, if you have,e.g. in the .html {{selectedMovie.director}} the app "crash" and no longer work, use the ? operator  {{selectedMovie?.director}}

The issue I'm describing isn't related to how Angular handles template binding or null safety with the ? operator. The problem is that after modifying the input (e.g., by deleting and re-typing a character), the selectedMovie variable is being set to a string (the movie title), instead of the full movie object, even though forceSelection is set to true.
The expected behavior is that after such modification, selectedMovie should always remain an object (or null if no valid object is selected), but in this case, it's being set to a string, which causes issues.

Sorry, I can not reproduce the problem in your stackblitz. this is the reason I think the problem is in another place :(
